# How to access multi-level json tree in PHP for database insertion

Tags: php, json

I am accessing an API where the JSON data is returned as below.

```
{
"name": "",
"count": 4,
"frequency": "",
"version": 3,
"newdata": true,
"lastrunstatus": "success",
"thisversionstatus": "success",
"thisversionrun": "",
"results": {
    "collection": [{
        "textlink": {
            "href": "http://text1.com",
            "text": "Text 1"
        },
        "index": 1,
        "url": ""
    }, {
        "textlink": {
            "href": "http://text2.com",
            "text": "Text 2"
        },
        "index": 2,
        "url": ""
    }, {
        "textlink": {
            "href": "http://text3.com",
            "text": "Text 3"
        },
        "index": 3,
        "url": ""
    }, {
        "textlink": {
            "href": "http://text4.com",
            "text": "Text 4"
        },
        "index": 4,
        "url": ""
    }]
}}
```

As you can see the JSON tree returned has multi-step levels.  I am wanting to be able to take some of the deeper levels, in PHP, and insert into a database.

Currently I am using this code to try and echo the data (once I am able to I can then work on inserting it to a database no problem)

```
<?php
$request = "API.REQUEST.NET";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);

foreach($results as $item) {

echo $item->results[0]->collection[0]->textlink[0]->href;
echo "<br>";
echo $item->results->collection['href'];
echo "<br>";
echo $item->results->collection['text'];

}
?>
```

As you can see above I have tried several ways to access the deeper levels f data that are being displayed but with no avail.

I am currently getting errors of 'trying to get property of a non-object'. How is it possible to reach the data in this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
echo $results['results']['collection'][0]['textlink']['href'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only returns the first result. How would the foreach loop be edited so that all results are displayed?

Comment: @Liam-FD you're looping through the first level of `$results` which is everything on your json. Consider to loop as  `foreach ($results['results']['collection'] as $item)` then use `$item['index']`, `$item['textlink']['href']` and so on.

Comment: Something like this: //echo '<pre>';
foreach($results['results']['collection'] as $item) {
 //echo print_r($item); 
 echo $item['textlink']['href'];
} You can uncomment the lines to get a preformatted version to see the keys you can target

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do something like this (According to me, correct way to fetch results from API responses):

```
<?php
$request = "API.REQUEST.NET";
$response = file_get_contents($request);

$response = json_decode($response);

foreach($response->results->collection as $item) {

echo $item->textlink->href;
echo "<br>";
echo $item->textlink->text;
echo "<br>";
echo $item->index;
echo "<br>";
echo $item->url;

}
?>
```

Comment: This still returns a Trying to get property of non-object error on this line
     `foreach($response->results->collection as $item) {`

Comment: If response is valid object, you should be able fetch it, can you show result of var_dump of response.

Comment: Check updated answer. Response should be object now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = json_decode( $json, true ); foreach ( $obj['key'] as $key => $value ) { echo $value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($response['results']['collection'] as $textlink) {
 $row = $textlink['textlink'];
 echo $row['href'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['text'];
 echo "<br>";
}
```

you can do foreach like this, which loops only items in collection